# How to check a radio button based upon the enum value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an enum. Based upon the value brought by model, I have to check radio button.  How can I do that?

```
<%=Html.RadioButton("Role", Role.Viewer)%><%= .Role.Viewer%>
        <%=Html.RadioButton("Role",.Role.Reporter)%><%= Role.Reporter%>
        <%=Html.RadioButton("Role",Role.User)%><%= Role.User%>
```

My enum would be having the numbers 1 to 3 for e.g.  How can I check the Role.Viewer if enum value selected is 1?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can cast the enum values to int without any problems:

```
<%=Html.RadioButton("Role", (int)Role.Viewer)%><%= (int)Role.Viewer%>
<%=Html.RadioButton("Role", (int)Role.Reporter)%><%= (int)Role.Reporter%>
<%=Html.RadioButton("Role", (int)Role.User)%><%= (int)Role.User%>
```

Bear in mind that the enum definition implicitly has a 0-based index. If you want more control, you can manually assign int values to the enum yourself:

```
public enum Role {
    Viewer = 1,
    Reporter = 2,
    User = 3
}
```

**[Update]**

Based on your comments, I get that you want to bind a database value to the radiolist. You can do that by using the following code:

```
<%=Html.RadioButton("Role", (int)Role.Viewer, Model.Role == Role.Viewer)%><%= (int)Role.Viewer%>
<%=Html.RadioButton("Role", (int)Role.Reporter, Model.Role == Role.Reporter)%><%= (int)Role.Reporter%>
<%=Html.RadioButton("Role", (int)Role.User, Model.Role == Role.User)%><%= (int)Role.User%>
```

This code assumes the database value is synced with Model.Role, but you can replace it with your own logic of course. And there are [more elegant ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263336/asp-net-mvc-radio-button-state/622986#622986) to write the radiobutton enumeration, but for only 3 radio options, it's safe to stick to this solution.

Comment: That`s helpful, how do I check button based on the value return.  eg, let`s say 1 has been returned, I will need to select the Role.Viewer radio button and the others remained unchanged?

Comment: You can do that by casting the int value back to the enum: `var myRole = (Role)returnValue;`.

Comment: I think you haven`t understood my question.  I retrieve the values from my database, and from that I find Role selected is number 3.  I need to check the radio button for Role.User.  If other numbers return, their corresponding buttons have to be checked, upon loading.

Comment: Updated my answer for you with a sample for that.

Comment: it`s not working , the radio button isn`t being checked accordingly!

Comment: Actually the code you provided is working but only one radio button selected!

Comment: How can we use Html.|radiobuttonfor in this case?

Comment: A `RadioButtonList` is for a single selection only. If you want multiple selected items, then you should use a `CheckboxList` and not a `RadioButtonList`. Don't know if it's been added in MVC2, but you could add it yourself. See this link how to do this: http://blogs.msdn.com/miah/archive/2008/11/10/checkboxlist-helper-for-mvc.aspx